# Можно ли с помощью jQuery получить текущую дату и время?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Т.е. на javascript'е `var date = new Date()`, а именно в jQuery есть такое?

Comment: Просто мимо проходил: а зачем именно jQuery?

Comment: jQuery поддерживает все, что используется в Java-script. Ибо это одна из библиотек JS.

Comment: Хз. Может и есть, но скорее всего обертка на тему того, что у вас написано.

Comment: Нельзя конечно, jQuery на это не способен... К сожалению разработчики "языка" jQuery - не предусмотрели работу с датой :(

А нет, ну `now` у вас есть :D

Comment: Вопрос был именно к тому, что через js это слишком длинно как мне кажется. Хотелось бы что-то типа $.date(format)

Comment: @nMike - Что мешает написать функцию, которая подготовит для вас дату-время-сутки-год, так, как это нужно именно вам? Примеров работы с датой в js в интернете много. Насчет именно jquery -> НАФИГА?

Answer (score 5):

Поймите, что jQuery - это библиотека JavaScript, фреймворк. Если очень образно объяснить, чтоб вы уловили суть, то jQuery избавляет от написания больших кодов. К примеру, на PHP есть функция *sort()*, которая сортирует массивы. Не составит большого труда написать самому такую функцию, но кода получиться гораздо больше и время убъем, поэтому мы не задумываясь используем *sort()*. Возвращаясь к вашему вопросу... Что вам мешает использовать *var date = new Date()*? Или вы хотите этот код сократить до трёх символов?

Answer (score 5):

меня заинтриговал этот вопрос:

```js
$.date = function() {
  return new Date().toLocaleString();
};

console.log($.date());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

ещё можно добавить всякие опции, как положено для полноценного плагина.

хотя если порыться в документации можно найти даже [jQuery.now()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.now/)

```js
console.log($.now())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле  [есть такой](http://arshaw.com/xdate/) плагин, вот только использовать его исключительно ради сокращения записи не рационально :)

Answer (score -1):

Ответ - нет, нет и ещё раз нет!!! Вы можете заниматься "глупством" и писать custom-функции для jQuery, которые в одну строку пишуться родным javaScript... но зачем??? зачем???

**P.S.** Вот запомните следующее для себя!!!!

```
Что такое jQuery? - Правильно, фрэймворк.    
А для чего нужен фрэймворк? - Облегчить процесс написания кода (краткость + информативность кода). Слоган jQuery: Write less, do more.
```

А может ещё с jQuery складывать числа? Или выводить стандартный alert()? Зачем??? Может jQuery должен вообще за вас (вас - это всех программистов, кто считает, что в jQuery есть ВСЁ) работать с БД, проводить аутентификацию, создавать файлы на сервере, шифровать данные, упаковыватьраспаковывать архивы, или вообще быть веб-сервером, осуществляя URL-реврайтинг и обрабатывая асинхронные запросы клиентов с пулом потоков?

На главной странице jQuery: **jQuery is a fast and concise JavaScript Library that simplifies HTML document traversing, event handling, animating, and Ajax interactions for rapid web development.**

Учитесь учиться!

Comment: мде... ответ вообще списан с предыдущих ответов и комментариев... какой понт? или ты родился уже всезнающим?

Comment: В вашем ответе слишком мало jQuery

Comment: @Palmervan, когда я начал писать ответ никаких ответов до меня не было. Просто на все вопросы, на которые мог ответить пооткрывал вкладки и нажал "Ответить на вопрос", а потом по по-порядочку отвечал. Получилось, что до этого вопроса долго доходил.


Я не родился всезнающим, но прочитать для чего фреймворк jQuery (хотя бы на офф-сайте) - для этого много знаний не нужно.

Comment: @megacoder за идиота меня держишь? Между первыми двумя ответами, комментариям к вопросу и твоим ответом - 6 часов разницы! XD)

Comment: что со мной не так? прочитал "...**raped** web development."

Comment: @Palmervan, главное кем себя выставишь, тем тебя и будут считать...

Вкладка у меня висела долго, потому что заряд на ноуте сел, а 220В нигде не было. Вышел с мобильника, но решил, что замучаюсь писать ответ с него и решил подождать пока вернусь домой. Ах да ещё... пришёл домой, выпил кофе, принял душ, немного отдохнул, к этому времени заряд появился и написал ответ. Такой отчёт ВАС устроит???????

Comment: А вот и неправильно, это библиотека.